# Javascript ES6 MultiplyBy10

Tags: javascript

I have finally taken the plunge. I watched the first lecture and the first homework question looked like this:

> Return num after multiplying it by 10

```
function multiplyByTen(num) {
}
```

I watched the video again and used similar syntax.

All of my answers have been wrong. I think I need to see what this looks like, and the other 10 questions would become much easier.

Comment: `const multiplyBy10 = (x) => 10 * x; console.log(multiplyBy10(5));`

Comment: `function times(n){ return n * this;} var multiplyByTen=times.bind(10);`

Comment: If i'm not wrong, the rule of stackoverflow is not allowing any homework, exercise questions :)

Comment: Please post at least one of your answers, so we can help you understand what you did wrong.

Comment: Thank you. When the system showed me my answers wrong, it said it expected a value of 50. I am not sure where the 5 is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

Refer [Arrow functions in MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

As @david Commented to your question.
Following solution would be the one you are looking for.

```js
const multiplyBy10 = (x) => 10 * x; 
console.log(multiplyBy10(5));
```